# Cannot serialize socket object, or a streaming video

Tags: python, sockets, video-streaming, dji-sdk

I'm trying to have control to a Tello drone, using TelloPy with Linux (Ubuntu).
When I want to handle the control of video and flight, I have to start a multiprocess task, passing some arguments and a streaming reference via pickling. But I had a problem where I describe below.

```
Tello: 21:54:34.226:  Info: start video thread
Tello: 21:54:34.227:  Info: video receive buffer size = 425984
Tello: 21:54:34.229:  Info: send connection request (cmd="conn_req:9617")
Tello: 21:54:34.229:  Info: state transit State::disconnected -> State::connecting
Tello: 21:54:34.277:  Info: connected. (port=9617)
Tello: 21:54:34.278:  Info: send_time (cmd=0x46 seq=0x01e4)
Tello: 21:54:34.278:  Info: state transit State::connecting -> State::connected

START PROCESS

Tello: 21:54:34.279:  Info: get video stream
Tello: 21:54:34.280:  Info: start video (cmd=0x25 seq=0x01e4)
Cannot serialize socket object
Tello: 21:54:34.280:  Info: quit
Tello: 21:54:34.281:  Info: state transit State::connected -> State::quit
Tello: 21:54:34.281:  Info: VideoStream.handle_event(DISCONNECTED)
bye
Tello: 21:54:34.328:  Info: recv: ack: cmd=0x34 seq=0x0000 cc 60 00 27 90 34 00 00 00 00 72 a5
Tello: 21:54:34.329:  Info: exit from the recv thread.
Tello: 21:54:35.228:  Info: exit from the video thread.
```

Where an unexpected **Cannot serialize socket object** was thrown.

I don't know, how to send as parameter a streaming video. Some one may give an idea, how to solve this?

Comment: For Windows, a socket connection can be transferred with `socket.share()` (see docs for details)

Comment: I'm using Linux Ubuntu